simple connected graph with $\delta\leq \frac{n-1}{2}$ contains $2\delta$-path
The background is Bondy & Murty GTM 211 Graph Theory Exercise 18.3.5:

18.3.5 Let $G$ be a simple graph of minimum degree $\delta$. Show that:
a) $G$ contains a path of length $2\delta$ if $G$ is connected and $\delta \leq (n − 1)/2$,
b) $G$ is traceable if $δ \geq (n − 1)/2$.

(b) can be solved by adding a vertex $v$ and joining it to all vertices of $G$, then use Dirac Theorem. But I cannot solve (a). I think we should use path exchange and assume the lenghth of the longest path is less than $2\delta$ then deduce contradiction, but I have no solid idea. Below is my attempt, but $\delta+\ell+1-n$ can be negative, so $S^-$ can be empty set, which cannot deduce any more.
Any suggestion or hints welcome.

Consider the longest path $P=v_1\cdots v_{\ell}$, if $\ell <2\delta\leq n-1$, then there is a vertex $u$ out of $P$ joining $\geq \delta-(n-1-\ell)=\delta+\ell+1-n$ vertices in $P-\{v_1,v_\ell\}$, because $v_1, v_\ell$ cannot join any vertices out of $P$, or contradict to the longest path. Now we have set $S^-=\{v_i|v_{i+1}u\in E\}\subset \{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_{\ell-2}\}, |S^-|\geq \delta+\ell+1-n$. On the other hand $v_\ell$ joins $\geq \delta-1$ vertices in $\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_{\ell-2}\}$, therefore
$$\begin{aligned}
|S^-\cap N(v_{\ell})\cap \{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_{\ell-2}\}|&\geq |S^-|+|N(v_\ell)\cap \{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_{\ell-2}\}|-|\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_{\ell-2}\}|\\
&\geq (\delta+\ell+1-n)+(\delta-1)-(\ell-2)=2\delta-n+2\geq 1
\end{aligned}$$
then we have $v_i\in V(P)$ joining to $v_\ell$ and $v_{i+1}u\in E$, then we have path $P'=v_1 P v_i v_\ell P v_{i+1} u$, which is longer then $P$, this is a contradiction.


Suppose that a longest path $P$ has $l\leq 2\delta$ vertices. We don't need to analyze how many vertices of $P$ are adjacent to $u$ outside $P$. All we need is that $u$ exists and has one neighbour in $P$, which follows from connectivity and $P$ having $l<n$ vertices.
Observe that if $G[V(P)]$ contains a cycle on $l$ vertices, we can find a path $l+1$ vertices using $V(P)$ and $u$. We now show such a cycle exists.

If $v_1$ and $v_l$ are adjacent, we are done. Note that by the maximality of $P$, all neighbours of $v_1$ and $v_l$ are in $P$. If $v_l$ is adjacent to $v_i$ and $v_1$ is adjacent to $v_{i+1}$ then $v_1\dots v_i v_l v_{l-1}\dots v_{i+1}$ is the cycle we want. Thus, we may assume that for each neighbour $v_i$ of $v_l$, $v_{i+1}$ is a non-neighbour of $v_1$. But $v_l$ has $\delta$ neighbours, so $v_1$ has $\delta$ non-neighbours in $P\backslash v_1$. This implies $P$ has $2\delta +1$ vertices, a contradiction.

